# Why does my Enum.reduce based implementation of Enum.all? return an empty list?

Tags: elixir

The Elixir help page for [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html?#reduce/3) says that almost all of the `Enum` functions can be implemented on top of `Enum.reduce/3`.  I am trying to implement `Enum.all?/1` by writing a new function that uses `Enum.reduce/3`. It works correctly most of the time but in some cases it returns an empty list.

In one case I have invoked the function passing a `1..7` range and a function testing that a value is less than `7`.  In another case I passed the `1..7` range and a function testing that a value is less than `8`.

In the first case my `all?/1` function correctly returns false as all values are not less than `7`.

In the second case I am expecting true, all values are less than `8` but instead get back an empty list.

Here is my implementation of the `all?/1` function .....

```
defmodule ListsRec5 do

  def all?(enumerable, acc, fun \\fn x -> x end) do
    enumerable
      |> Enum.reduce([], fn x, acc -> fun.(x) and acc end)
  end

end
```

The first test......

```
ListsRec5.all?(1..7, true, fn x -> x < 7 end)
false
```

The second test ....

```
ListsRec5.all?(1..7, true, fn x -> x < 8 end)
[]
```

I think the second test should return `true`, not an empty list.

Comment: Why? You're `and`ing `true` with an empty array, that'll eval to the empty array. `false and []` short-circuits so you get `false`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're reducing into a boolean (reduce won't be the best approach here, but it can be done), your accumulator is going to be a boolean, not a list, and each iteration will be a boolean representing "everything prior was true and this one is true".

```rb
Enum.reduce(enumerable, true, fn x, acc -> acc and fun.(x) end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using incorrectly the accumulator passed to `reduce/3`

```
  def all?(enumerable, fun \\fn x -> x end) do
    enumerable
      |> Enum.reduce(true, fn x, acc -> fun.(x) and acc end)
  end
```

The arity of `all?` function is 2 (not 3)

The initial value passed to the reduce function should be true

Answer (score -1):

> The second test .... ListsRec5.all?(1..7, true, fn x -> x < 8 end) []
>
> I think the second test should return true, not an empty list.

Well, let's see:

```
iex(3)> true and []  
[]
iex(4)> true and []
[]
iex(5)> true and []
[]
iex(6)> true and []
[]
iex(7)> true and []
[]
iex(8)> true and []
[]
iex(9)> true and []
[]
```

Yup, that's an empty list.  I've read that:

1. `and` requires boolean arguments and returns a boolean.
2. `and` requires the first argument to be a boolean and returns a boolean.

The example above disproves both of those incompetent claims.  So, lets ignore the Elixir writer's vain attempts to explain how `and` works because apparently `and` in Elixir is equivalent to `andalso` in Erlang.  So let's check the Erlang [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#short-circuit-expressions):

> ```
>  Expr1 andalso Expr2
> ```
>
> Returns either the value of Expr1 (false) or the
>   value of Expr2 (if Expr2 is evaluated).

So, if Expr1 is true, then andalso returns Expr2, otherwise andalso returns false, i.e. when Expr1 is false.

> From Erlang/OTP R13A, Expr2 is no longer required to evaluate to a
>   Boolean value.

That explains why you are getting an empty list:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> true andalso false.
false

2> true andalso [].
[]

3> true andalso 10.
10

4> false andalso "hello".
false
```

Also notice here:

```
  def all?(enumerable, acc, fun \\fn x -> x end) do
    enumerable
    |> Enum.reduce([], fn x, acc -> fun.(x) and acc end)
  end
```

that the `acc` variable in the all? def's parameter list is unused.  The function should be defined like this:

```
   def all?(enumerable, acc, fun \\fn x -> x end) do
     enumerable
     |> Enum.reduce(acc, fn x, curr_acc -> fun.(x) and curr_acc end)
   end
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex a.ex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> A.all?(1..7, true, fn x -> x<8 end)
true

iex(2)> A.all?(1..7, true, fn x -> x<7 end)
false
```

Somewhere in the looping you will get `acc=true and false`, which returns `false`, and thereafter `false and anything` will return `false`.  As a result, if the predicate function returns `false` for any element in the enumerable, then the end result will be `false`.